# Foursquare API different results on Explore venues

Tags: api, foursquare

> https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?v=20140504&ll=44.3,37.2&limit=5&sortByDistance=1&query=chocolate&oauth_token=myToken

Why do the Explore venue responses differ every time? This happens both in userless and oauth mode. The problem is that sometimes I can get the most recent tips to my query but sometimes I get some tips from 2012 or something.

I only want the most recent tips.
Am I missing something here or is this a bug? And if it is where can I submit it?